# Play music from front speaker on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, speaker

Is it possible to play music from the front speaker of an iPhone instead of the rear speaker? I mean, the speaker used for classical phone calls instead of the rear loudspeaker.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible in the public API's that iOS exposes to its developers. More important is the reason for such a requirement on your part. Why do you need this ?

Also the front speaker is low in volume capacity but perfect for receiving phone calls; maybe not for playing music...

Apple probably would have spent large amount of money & research in figuring out the correct acoustics (and probably other factors) for placing the speaker where it is. Why would you want to tinker with that?

Comment: I want to use it to play a speech in a place where loudspeakers are not allowed. I'll simply check if the headphones are connected in. Thanks

Comment: glad I could help. If my answer helped you in any way please upvote or mark the answer as correct. thanks...

Comment: I'm not sure but WhatsApp is doing this with voice recordings. When you put your phone on ear, It continue to play on front speaker so It may be..